# Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server

I get an error when running a query.
The error is:
Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

Code:

```
select g0.docnumber as docnumber
    , g0.datum
    , g0.crdnr
    , datepart(quarter, g0.datum) as quarter
    , g0.bkjrcode
    , g0.periode
    , sum(g0.[Toner Virgin]) as [Toner Virgin]
    , sum(g0.[Inkt Virgin]) as [Inkt Virgin]
    , sum(g0.[Non Virgin]) as [Non Virgin]
    , sum(g0.Mix) as Mix
    , sum(g0.Fusers) as Fusers
    , sum(g0.[Full]) as [Full]
    , sum(g0.Mobiel) as Mobiel
    , sum(g0.inkoop) as inkoop
    , cast(sum(g0.omzet) as decimal(8, 2)) as omzet
    , max(g0.doos) as doos
    , max(g0.pallet) as pallet
from (
    select g.docnumber
        , g.bkjrcode
        , g.periode
        , g.datum
        , a.crdnr
        , case 
            when i.assortment = '130'
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as [Toner Virgin]
        , case 
            when i.assortment = '230'
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as [Inkt Virgin]
        , case 
            when i.assortment in ('120', '220')
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as [Non Virgin]
        , case 
            when i.assortment in ('110', '210')
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as Mix
        , case 
            when i.assortment = '140'
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as Fusers
        , case 
            when i.assortment in ('100', '200')
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as [Full]
        , case 
            when i.assortment between '300'
                    and '330'
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as Mobiel
        , case 
            when i.assortment = '900'
                then g.aantal
            else 0
            end as Afval
        , case 
            when i.assortment between '100'
                    and '330'
                or i.assortment = '900'
                then g.bdr_hfl
            else 0
            end as inkoop
        , a.doos
        , a.pallet
        , isnull(case 
                when i.assortment between '100'
                        and '330'
                    or i.assortment = '900'
                    then g.aantal * f.verkoop
                else 0
                end, 0) as omzet
    from [110]..gbkmut(nolock) g
    inner join [110]..items(nolock) i
        on i.itemcode = g.artcode
            and i.GLAccountDistribution = g.reknr
    left outer join (
        select f.artcode
            , sum((f.esr_aantal * (f.prijs_n * f.koers - ((f.prijs_n * f.koers / 100) * f.korting)))) as verkoop
        from [110]..frhsrg(nolock) f
        where f.fakdat >= getdate() - 365
            and f.esr_aantal > 0
        group by f.artcode
        ) as f
        on f.artcode = g.artcode
    inner join (
        select a.hid
            , c.crdnr
            , case 
                when a.FreeTextField_11 = '00DOOS'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_01, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_12 = '00DOOS'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_02, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_13 = '00DOOS'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_03, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_14 = '00DOOS'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_04, 0)
                else 0
                end as doos
            , case 
                when a.FreeTextField_11 <> '00DOOS'
                    and left(a.FreeTextField_11, 2) = '00'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_01, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_12 <> '00DOOS'
                    and left(a.FreeTextField_12, 2) = '00'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_02, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_13 <> '00DOOS'
                    and left(a.FreeTextField_13, 2) = '00'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_03, 0)
                else 0
                end + case 
                when a.FreeTextField_14 <> '00DOOS'
                    and left(a.FreeTextField_14, 2) = '00'
                    then isnull(a.FreeNumberField_04, 0)
                else 0
                end as pallet
        from [synergy]..absences(nolock) a
        inner join [synergy]..cicmpy(nolock) c
            on c.cmp_wwn = a.CustomerID
        where a.type = '1000'
            and a.status <> '2'
            and c.textfield3 = 'AM'
            and (
                left(a.FreeTextField_11, 2) = '00'
                or left(a.FreeTextField_12, 2) = '00'
                or left(a.FreeTextField_13, 2) = '00'
                or left(a.FreeTextField_14, 2) = '00'
                )
        ) as a
        on cast(a.hid as varchar(max)) = (
                select max(g1.docnumber)
                from [110]..gbkmut(nolock) g1
                where g.bkstnr = g1.bkstnr
                    and g1.reknr = '   170200'
                )
    where g.transtype = 'N'
        and g.transsubtype = 'T'
        and ltrim(rtrim(g.dagbknr)) = '72'
    ) as g0
group by g0.docnumber
    , g0.datum
    , g0.crdnr
    , g0.bkjrcode
    , g0.periode
```

I am using a number of subqueries. The error is triggered from within the subquery that starts with 'left outer join (select f.artcode' and ends on the line containing ') as f on f.artcode=g.artcode'.

Within this subquery the line

`sum((f.esr_aantal * (f.prijs_n * f.koers - ((f.prijs_n * f.koers / 100) * f.korting)))) as verkoop`

is causing the error.

All fields in this specific line within the subquery are float types.

Outside this subquery I am using the field 'f.verkoop'.

I have tried to convert all the fields from float to decimal(10,3) but still get the error.

Does anybody know what is wrong with my code?

Eeko

Comment: Can you provide a sample row that failed?

Comment: `DECIMAL (10, 3)` might not be enough. I'd suggest you "go crazy" and use something like `DECIMAL(38, 5)`. `DECIMAL(10, 3)` are numbers between `9.999.999,999 and -9.999.999,999` so if your set of multiplications / divisions etc. don't fit in that (even partial mathematical operations, not the entire result) then you'll get an error.

Comment: There are `decimal(8,2)` i see

Comment: Not a solution to your current issue but you might want to read this before you continue splattering NOLOCK hints all over your system. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Jacob H.: The row that fails is 'omzet'.

Comment: Radu Gheorghiu: I have added a cast statement to all fields to cast to decimal(38,38). Still the same error.

Comment: Sean Lange: Thank you for sharing the link. I am going to ask our IT partner why they have learned me to always use NOLOCK.